# Compiling standard library types

Tags: c++, dictionary, types

I would have expected the following code  to produce an error:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #include <map>
    #include <string>
    int main(){
       map<string,string> x; 
       x["10"]=20;
       cout <<x["10"]<<endl;
    }
```

because the assigned value is not of type string.  However, there is no error.  But the output is incorrect -- nothing visible is printed.  However, if I enclose 20 in quotes then the output is fine.  Can anyone explain

Comment: You can shorten this to `int main() { string s; s = 20; cout << s;`} - the map is unimportant. Then look at [the 4th assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) for `std::string` and try values like 65, 66, 67, ... Then examine an ASCII table.

Comment: 20 is casted to a one-character string

Comment: @Neywat A single character is not a one-character string.

Comment: Thanks to both.  I assume this is as per the C++ standard.  But I would have expected the cast to produce "20".  Is there a reason why it produces a single character, presumably of ASCII value 20?

Comment: @Ekalavya An `int` can be implicitly converted to `char`; `char` is an integer type. (And there is no casting, but an implicit conversion. Casting is an explicit conversion.)

Comment: [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452738/4730685) do `using namespace std;`, _especially_ not before other `#include` directives. If you must use it, do it after all the `#include`s.

Comment: Yes, I see now that an int is naturally viewed as a char and hence naturally cast to a string.

Comment: What is missing by the given answer? Do you need more information or is something wrong with it? It simply ask because you did not accept the answer...

Comment: I upvoted the answers I liked, and my question has been answered satisfactorily.  How do I "accept" ?  I would like to accept the remarks made by molbdnilo and close this conversation for myself.

Comment: @Ekalavya: Simply press the check mark under the vote buttons. BTW: If you answer to a comment, you should add a @<name> to your comment, so the person will be informed.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` has 3 versions of `operator=` ( C++03 ). One of them takes a single char. If you present `s = 65;` it takes the int as a char and calls the `string& operator= (char c);` version. `std::string` creates a single character string in this case.

The 3 versions in C++03 are:

```
string& operator= (const string& str);
string& operator= (const char* s);
string& operator= (char c);
```

For current standard we have some more, see [std::string::operator=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D)

Example: Prints out "A" because 65 is in ASCII the upper case `A`.

```
int main()
{   
    std::string s;
    s = 65; 
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Your observation is *not* related to use in combination with the map, so I reduced it to the use of `std::string`.